# Removing /n from print after web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-cleaning

I'm trying to capture some columns from the following link:

[https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Frecuentes-(1-1000)-Subt%C3%ADtulos_de_pel%C3%ADculas](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Frecuentes-(1-1000)-Subt%C3%ADtulos_de_pel%C3%ADculas%20(b))

The code I've come up with is as follows:

```
import requests
wiki_url = "https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Frecuentes-(1-1000)-Subt%C3%ADtulos_de_pel%C3%ADculas"
wiki_texto = requests.get(wiki_url).text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
wiki_datos = BeautifulSoup(wiki_texto, "html")

wiki_filas = wiki_datos.findAll("tr")
print(wiki_filas[1])

print("...............................")

wiki_celdas = wiki_datos.findAll("td")
print(wiki_celdas[0:])

fila_1 = wiki_celdas[0:]
info_1 = [elemento.get_text() for elemento in fila_1]
print(fila_1)
print(info_1)
info_1[0] = int(float(info_1[0]))
print(info_1)


print("...............................")

num_or = [int(float(elem.findAll("td")[0].get_text())) for elem in wiki_filas[1:]]
palabras = [elem.findAll("td")[1].get_text() for elem in wiki_filas[1:]]
frecuencia = [elem.findAll("td")[2].get_text() for elem in wiki_filas[1:]]

print(num_or[0:])
print(palabras[0:])
print(frecuencia[0:])

from pandas import DataFrame
tabla = DataFrame([num_or, palabras, frecuencia]).T
tabla.columns = ["Núm. orden", "Palabras", "Frecuencia"]
print(tabla.head())
```

The problem is that I can't remove the following **/n** from colums "Palabras" and "Frecuencia":

[image]

**Any ideas? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: you can use `get_text(strip=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that `rstrip()` method should help you:

```
palabras = [elem.findAll("td")[1].get_text().rstrip() for elem in wiki_filas[1:]]
frecuencia = [elem.findAll("td")[2].get_text().rstrip() for elem in wiki_filas[1:]]
```

You can also use `lstrip` for left side and `strip()` method for both sides of string.

edit: this removes all whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a newline.

You can remove it either with `.replace("\n", "")`:

```
palabras = [elem.findAll("td")[1].get_text().replace("\n", "") for elem in wiki_filas[1:]]
frecuencia = [elem.findAll("td")[2].get_text().replace("\n", "") for elem in wiki_filas[1:]]
```

Alternatively, `.strip()` removes any surrounding whitespace.